# Erasing from vector of list doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, graph, stl

It's a simple thing that I am doing but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
int main(){
    vector<list<int>> adjList(3);
    adjList[0].push_back(1);
    adjList[0].push_back(2);
    adjList[1].push_back(3);
    adjList[1].push_back(0);
    adjList[2].push_back(4);
    cout << "Original graph...\n";
    printGraph(adjList);

    cout << "\nAfter deleting the zeroth index...\n";

    adjList.erase(adjList.begin());

    printGraph(adjList);

    return 0;

}


Original graph...
0:1->2->NULL
1:3->0->NULL
2:4->NULL

After deleting the zeroth index...
0:3->0->NULL
1:4->NULL
```

I expected the zeroth index in my vector of list to be deleted. Instead, something weird happened where the second index got deleted and the elements in the list also got shuffled.

I am sure I am missing something basic here but just not able to figure out what that is.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: And why exactly did you expect that output? After all, only you know what's in `printGraph()`, and noone else (since you didn't show it).

Comment: My bad. I realize now what's wrong. I was expecting to see the same indices after deletion but the of course that is a wrong expectation.

Comment: A vector can't have "holes" in it. If you remove an element, all elements after it are shifted forward to fill the gap.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> adjList.erase(adjList.begin()+1);
> ```
>
> I expected the zeroth index in my vector of list to be deleted.

Your expectation is wrong.

`adjList.begin()+1` is an iterator to the element at index 1. Therefore erasing that iterator will cause the element at index 1 to be erased (i.e. the second element).

`adjList.begin()` is an iterator to the element at the index 0, so if your intention is to erase that element, then that is the iterator that you would need to erase. Note however, that if you need to often erase the first element of the sequence, and need to keep the sequence in original order, then a vector is an inefficient choice. In such case, you might want to consider using a deque.

---

> ```
>  adjList.erase(adjList.begin());
> ```
>
> I expected to get the below: 1:3->0->NULL 2:4->NULL

Your expectation is wrong.

A vector never skips any indices. If there are n elements in a vector, then those elements are in indices 0...n-1.

When you erase an element of a vector, the elements at greater indices are shifted to the left (this is why erasing from anywhere except at the end of the vector is slow).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it. But I still don't get the expected answer. I expected to get the below: 1:3->0->NULL 2:4->NULL

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I realize now what's wrong. I was expecting to see the same indices after deletion but of course that is a wrong expectation. So the output is actually right just the indices moved around.

```
Original graph...
0:1->2->NULL
1:3->0->NULL
2:4->NULL

After deleting the zeroth index...

0:3->0->NULL (index 1 becomes 0)
1:4->NULL (index 2 becomes 1)
```